# Find Rank in Microsoft Report

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc, ranking, microsoft-reporting

Is there any way I can find the rank of a set of values in Microsoft Reports?

For instance, in order to produce a table like the one below, what function/formula do I enter in the **Rank** column?

```
+------+-----+
|Value | Rank|
+------+-----+
| 12   | 3   |
| 30   | 5   |
|  5   | 1   |
| 10   | 2   |
| 24   | 4   |
+------+-----+
```

**Update**
Values in the value column are produced from calculations on the report-side so I cannot find the rank using a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you are going to get is the RowNumber function, but that depends on the underlying sort order.

I thoroughly recommend moving the value column logic server side and creating using SQL to get a rank value there.

Comment: I eventually had to move all the calculation logic to the server side (queries) in order to get the ranks working. I strongly think Microsoft **has to** build upon the Reporting Services though; it makes otherwise trivial functions too difficult.